# About the url used for firebase email authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a question regarding the url in the code below.

```js
var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
    // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
    // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
    url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
    // This must be true
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOSBundleId: 'com.example.ios',
    androidPackageName: 'com.example.android',
    // installIfNotAvailable
    androidInstallApp: true,
    // minimumVersion
    androidMinimumVersion: '12');
```

How should I do the `finishSignUp?cartId=1234` part ?

I would like to implement firebase_auth email link authentication using flutter. firebase is configured to allow email authentication and to allow "Email/Password" authentication. I have also acquired a domain name.